# Importing Virtual Environment Installed Packages into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I want to install the google-cloud-bigquery library into my Jupyter Notebooks project (project located within "EDF Boston" directory).  I already downloaded- via my command prompt- the "google-cloud-bigquery" library in my activated virtual environment (see code below)

```
(venv) C:\Users\Joe\Documents\EDF Boston\venv\Scripts>pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

The following code block I found online as something to run at the beginning of my code to import the google-cloud-bigquery library into my Jupyter Notebook project.  However, when I replace "" with "venv" and run the code, I get a syntax error.

```
!pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
<your-env>\Scripts\activate
<your-env>\Scripts\pip.exe install google-cloud-bigquery
```

I have tried opening a Jupyter Notebook both from within the virtual environment and from outside of it, but can't get it to work either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not need to use ***venv*** to run the Python BigQuery API within your Jupyter Notebook. You can install manually each necessary package using **pip**, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter). After installing the packages, inside your Python code use ***import package_name*** to use it within your script.

However, I would like to point that **venv** is used to create an isolated Python environment, which allows you to isolate project dependencies. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#installing_and_using_virtualenv), it is advisable to use ***venv*** when developing locally with Python. In order to use venv, follow the steps below:

1. Copy your entire Python installation:

   `cd your-project python3 -m venv venv`
2. Set your shell to use Venv paths

   `source venv/bin/activate`
3. Now install the packages without affecting other environments:

   `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`

   `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`
4. If you need to exit the environment:

   `deactivate`